# Activites overview keyboard navigation in multi-monitor environment

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, 18.04

We can use keyboard arrow keys to navigate between windows in Activities Overview (super key).

However, when using two and more monitors, Gnome allows to navigate between windows only in scope of single monitor, i.e. i can't navigate to application on second monitor from first monitor using arrow keys.

Are there any workarounds for such case ?

P.s. yep, there is an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher, with which i can operate using arrow keys, but the question is about Activities Overview.

**UPDATE**

I dived into gnome shell js source code, but stuck at

```
Main.overview.viewSelector._activePage.navigate_focus(null, Gtk.Destination.TAB_FORWRAD, false)
```

this function made me dive into `st-bin.c` code, where i found a whole mess of other calls.

So, the result, that i think - is to extend `Page` objects in `ViewSelector.js` to whole 3 monitors, such that `navigate_focus` will automatically switch to next window (among other windows within all 3 displays). The problem is that navigation functionality itself is tightly coupled with `C` backend.

**If anyone can help to deal with implementation - i and other users will be immensely grateful.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a very simple example (extension) on somehow to achieve explained behavior above:
https://github.com/up-to-you/gnome-overview-nav

This sample is only for proof of concepts (`alt+left`, `alt+right` for opening overview and focusing `left` or `right` monitor respectively).

If someone want to pick up a project and implement full working version -  everyone are welcome!